# Is this a counterexample for the Erdös-Szekeres Theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

As I understand, the Erdös-Szekeres theorem says that for every sequence $a_1$,$a_2$,...,$a_{n^2+1}$   of  $n^2+1$ real numbers, there is a subsequence of length $n+1$ which is either increasing or decreasing.

If I set $n=2$ and select my sequence to be ${1,3,2,5,4}$

Then I should have a subsequence of length $3$ which is either increasing or decreasing right?

I can't really see it happening, what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: 1,2,5 or 1,2,4 would do.  The subsequence need not be consecutive.

Comment: Oh you're right, I shouldn't have assumed that! Thank you

Comment: Also 1,3,5 and 1,3,4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBPj8E1JKaQ&app=desktop) covered this theorem. By $n^2+1$ it's forced to escape all positive lattice points, in an n by n grid, since they need to be distinct in at least 1 coordinate, they are forced to $n+1$ in one of the coordinates. They also don't need to be consecutive as has been pointed out.

Comment: Quite illuminating, thanks.

Comment: You can accept an answer at any time.

Answer (score 0):

$1,3,5$ (indices $1,2,4$) are such an increasing subsequence. They need not be consecutive, just in order. $1,2,4$ also works etc.